# Integration of exponential function 4

Tags: integration

How can I find the integral $\int e^{x^2}dx$ in terms of finite terms?

I know that this integration can be solved by using power series technique.

I am stuck on it. Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can. Do you have any specific reason to believe that it is possible?

Comment: This function has no elementary antiderivative. The definite integral can be evaluated in terms of the error function, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If expressing your integral in terms of a special function constitutes writing it in finite terms, then a primitive for your integral can be written in terms of the so-called [imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function) $\text{erfi} (x)$.

Defined as
$$\text{erfi} (x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x e^{t^2} \, dt,$$
we see that
$$\int e^{x^2} \, dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \text{erfi} (x) + C.$$

Note that despite the name *imaginary error function*, $\text{erfi}⁡ (x)$ is real when $x$ is real.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what finite terms means, but here is the power series technique you are talking about. Recall that
$$
e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!},
$$
thus
$$
e^{x^2}
  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left(x^2\right)^k}{k!}
  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{k!},
$$
so you have
$$
\int e^{x^2} dx
 = \int \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{k!} dx
 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int \frac{x^{2k}}{k!} dx
 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1) \cdot k!} + C
$$
but I don't think there an analytic representation of this series.

Comment: I was to mean with out  power series representation.

Comment: @UserAb you can use the error function for notation if you like, but either way you will not get a closed analytic form